# Form dependent field reactive form Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following data structure:

```
formAviso: FormGroup;

deapartamentos: [
  {nombre: 'Amazonas', codigo: 41},
  {nombre: 'Ancash', codigo: 43},
  {nombre: 'Apurimac', codigo: 83},
  ...
]

constructor() {
  this.formAviso = this.fb.group ({
    departamento: [ '', Validators.required ],
    codigoCiudad: [ '', Validators.required ],
  });
}
```

So in my reactive form it looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formAviso" (ngSubmit)="crearAviso()" novalidate>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <mat-select formControlName="departamento">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let departamento of departamentos [value]="departamento.nombre">{{departamento.nombre}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <mat-select formControlName="codigoCiudad">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let departamento of departamentos [value]="departamento.codigo">{{departamento.codigo}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

</form>
```

So my query is how I do so that when I select an item in `departmento`, the respective code number of that item is automatically selected in `codigoCiudad`. It's possible?

For example, if I select `Ancash`, the value selected in the second select should be `43`.

Comment: can it be changed after the fact? or do they always have to be matching values?

Comment: What's the point of having two different select boxes to select a single department?

Comment: @bryan60 Yes, they should be able to be changed after having selected in `departamento`

Comment: ok so just to be ultra clear, I am allowed to select a different code after selecting a department without changing the department/

Comment: @JBNizet the point is that in one select I want to select department and in the other its respective `codigo`

Comment: @bryan60 correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to do something like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.formAviso = this.fb.group ({
    departamento: [ '', Validators.required ],
    codigoCiudad: [ '', Validators.required ],
  });

  const deptCtrl = this.formAviso.get('departamento');
  const codCtrl = this.formAviso.get('codigoCiudad');
  deptCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(nombre => {
    if (nombre) {
      const dept = this.departamentos.find(d => d.nombre === nombre);
      if (dept)
        codCtrl.setValue(dept.codigo);
    }
  });
}
```

you might want to tweak the logic to your exact needs but the basics are that you subscribe to value changes of the department control and find the department and set the value of the code control with that value.

Comment: This worked perfect, just a typo, in the second `if` I had to add the brackets `{ }`

Comment: you shouldn't need brackets for a single line if statement

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to one field's changes and then update other field:

```
departamentos = [
  {nombre: 'Amazonas', codigo: 41},
  {nombre: 'Ancash', codigo: 43},
  {nombre: 'Apurimac', codigo: 83}
];
formAviso: FormGroup;

private departamentosMap = this.departamentos.reduce((res, curr) => ({
  ...res,
  [curr.nombre]: curr.codigo
}), {});

ngOnInit() {
  this.formAviso = this.fb.group ({
    departamento: [ '', Validators.required ],
    codigoCiudad: [ '', Validators.required ],
  });

  this.formAviso.get('departamento').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formAviso.get('codigoCiudad').setValue(this.departamentosMap[val]);
  });
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z5rgv?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe the the `valueChanges` of the first form control, and whenever a new nombre is emitted, find the corresponding code in your array, and set the value of the second form control:

```
this.formAviso.get('departamento').valueChanges.subscribe(
  newName => this.formAviso.get('codigoCiudad').setValue(this.findCodeFromName(newName))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume that the `finCodeFromName` function should be the logic of how to find the related `codigo`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" for both of them.
2. Use the same [value]="departamento.codigo" value for both of them.

   These two step will solve your problem.

   ```
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <mat-select formControlName="departamento" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let departamento of deapartamentos" [value]="departamento.codigo">{{departamento.nombre}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>

   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <mat-select formControlName="departamento" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let departamento of deapartamentos" [value]="departamento.codigo">{{departamento.codigo}}
         </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
   ```

Comment: thanks, the detail is that I am using reactive form with `formControlName` I think you can not use `ngModel` or if?

Comment: Sorry I changed it.. You can use with form control name. no need to delete. I tried it is worked with form control name. So you can use this.